# Change Android Signature

Tags: android, sign

Does it possible to change the signature of an android app? I want just change it from developer signature of my signature.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to take an APK that the developer signed and sign it with your own key? Seems nefarious to me.

Comment: @MattC it only for my development points. I try to run  another apps in my modified Dalvik VM

Answer (score 1):

You can upload a new version with a different signature. Just extract a new apk with versionCode + 1, and then use a new signature.

Comment: What Tool should I take for extracting .apk?

Answer (score 0):

I found creating new project easier than other solutions.